# How to tell a element and its childs to ignore a global style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visifire

To get a common look & feel in my application, I defined a global style for all my `TextBlock` elements like that:

**MainSkin.xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,5,0"/>
</Style>
```

Unfortunately this messes up a chart element (from external visifire library) I use and clippes some of the text elements (marked with red rectangle in screenshot):

[image]

**View.xaml**

```
xmlns:vc="clr-namespace:Visifire.Charts;assembly=WPFVisifire.Charts"

<vc:Chart>
    <vc:Chart.Titles>
        <vc:Title Text="SomeTitle" />
    </vc:Chart.Titles>
    <vc:Chart.AxesX>
        <vc:Axis Title="X" TitleFontSize="12" />
    </vc:Chart.AxesX>
    <vc:Chart.AxesY>
        <vc:Axis Title="Y" TitleFontSize="12"/>
    </vc:Chart.AxesY>
</vc:Chart>
```

From testing I know the `Margin` setting of the `TextBlock` style is causing this. I guess somewhere inside the `Chart` element, they use a `TextBlock` that my style affects.

**How can I tell the Chart element and its childs in Xaml to ignore the global TextBlock style?**

I tried setting the Chart style to null, without success.

Caveats:

- I don't want to edit external source code used in the Chart
- I don't want to use a x:Key with my style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create another `TextBlock` implicit style that doesn't set anything:

```
<vc:Chart>
    <vc:Chart.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" />
    </vc:Chart.Resources>

    <vc:Chart.Titles>
        <vc:Title Text="SomeTitle" />
    </vc:Chart.Titles>
    <vc:Chart.AxesX>
        <vc:Axis Title="X" TitleFontSize="12" />
    </vc:Chart.AxesX>
    <vc:Chart.AxesY>
        <vc:Axis Title="Y" TitleFontSize="12"/>
    </vc:Chart.AxesY>
</vc:Chart>
```